# How to use `\texorpdfstring`. Characters disappear

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks

I'm using `hyperref`, which causes trouble when having math in my section title.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\begin{document}
\section{Basis for CO\texorpdfstring{\textsubscript{2}{ h}} heat}
\section{Basis for CO\texorpdfstring{\textsubscript{2}} heat}
\section{Basis for CO\texorpdfstring{$_2$} heat}
\end{document}
```

The first text line will be displayed correctly, but why do I have to add `{ h}` (I know this is not the correct solution, but it works)? If I don't, the space and the `h` will disappear. I found out that I had to add it by trial and error. How should this be done?

Comment: `\texorpdfstring` takes two arguments: the first is typeset into the document, the second one is put in the bookmark. So `\textorpdfstring{\textsubscript{2}}{2}` for example.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: That's what I tried at first, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ROLF It works for me, given that `\textsubscript` is defined (which neither `report` nor `hyperref` nor `fixltx2e` (deprecated anyway) do).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Aha, I thought `\textsubscript` was a standard thing. How should it be defined?

Comment: `\textsubscript` is now in the LaTeX kernel (01/2015). You should redo your formats.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`\texorpdfstring` has *two* arguments, the first is the normal TeX code, the second is a string, which can be used as replacement for the arbitrary TeX in the bookmarks.

If option `unicode` (or `pdfencoding=auto`) is enabled, then the subscript `2` is available as `\texttwoinferior`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}% faster updated bookmarks
\begin{document}
\section{Basis for
  CO\texorpdfstring{\textsubscript{2}}{\texttwoinferior} heat}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm confused why it looks just fine in my PDF bookmarks without \texorpdfstring despite the warning in the compile log? I mean, sure, it's not latex-ed, but in my case the chemical formula CO2 was cleanly replaced with just CO2. But i still get the warning.

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye The formula is `CO₂` rather than `CO2`. There are lots of ways to write chemical formulas in LaTeX, also there are lots of warnings. Without knowing neither of them, helping is difficult. Maybe, make a new question with a minimal example and the full warning.