# Subscript within a fraction

Tags: subscripts, fractions

I am trying to use subscripts within a fraction. Using them each on their own works fine, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\texorpdfstring{n\textsubscript{subscript}} \\ \\

\( \frac{n}{2} \) \\ \\ 

\end{document}
```

I get the desired result:

[image]

However, when I combine them into

```
\( \frac{\texorpdfstring{n\textsubscript{subscript}} }{2} \)
```

I get the following error:

```
/Users/niklas/workspace/udemy_tex/my_ownfile/test.tex:15: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\frac  #1#2->{\begingroup #1\endgroup \@@over #2}

l.15 ...pdfstring{n\textsubscript{subscript}} }{2}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you want to use `\texorpdfstring`? In math mode you should consider just switchin to `n_{\text{subscript}}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \`\texorpdfstring\`. Characters disappear](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249107/how-to-use-texorpdfstring-characters-disappear)

Comment: I agree the referenced possible duplicate does solve the problem; however, as TeXnician rightly points out, the real problem is not erroneous use of \texorpdfstring, but rather that a different method which does not involve \texordpdfstring, but the simpler `\( \frac{n_{\text{subscript}}}{2} \)` should be preferred.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been solved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `\texorpdfstring` the wrong way (as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249107/how-to-use-texorpdfstring-characters-disappear)), since `\texorpdfstring` expects a second argument (else the "or" would be senseless). So trying with:

```
\(\frac{\texorpdfstring{n\textsubscript{subscript}}{nsub}}{2}\)
```

would also work.

[image: fractions]

*Update:* Of course you should avoid using such complex mechanisms if you just want to have a subscript in math. LaTeX's own `\(n_{\text{subscript}}\)` is just sufficient.