# \mathsmaller in section title incompatible with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, amsmath, relsize

I would like to use `\mathsmaller` in a section title but it is incompatible with `hyperref`. Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}    %automatically loads ansbsy which gives \boldsymbol
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

$\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}$%compiles

$\mathsmaller{SQUARING^{+}}$%compiles

$\mathsmaller{\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}}$%compiles

\section{$\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}$ }%compiles

%\section{Function $\mathsmaller{SQUARING}^{+}$ }%does NOT compile with hyperref

%\section{Function $\mathsmaller{\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}}$}%does NOT compiles with hyperref

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your claim "does NOT compile with hyperref" is not quite right: The code does compile, but with several *warning* (not error) messages.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Have a look at the [`\texorpdfstring` macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249107), to be used in sectioning headers. The second argument -- with the material that's to be written to the pdf bookmark -- should contain no TeX-type math code.
- My personal opinion is that the result looks pretty ugly :).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

$\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}$%compiles
$\mathsmaller{SQUARING^{+}}$%compiles
$\mathsmaller{\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}}$%compiles

% note the use of \texorpdfstring in `\section` directives
\section{%
    \texorpdfstring{$\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}$}% Code for text
                   {SQUARING+}% Code for PDF bookmark
}
\section{%
    \texorpdfstring{$\mathsmaller{SQUARING}^{+}$}% Code for text
                   {SQUARING+}% Code for PDF bookmark
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

### Edit 2022-01-26

```
% 3rd Version
\section{%
    \texorpdfstring{$\mathsmaller{\mathcal{SQUARING}^{+}}$}% Code for text
                   {SQUARING+}% Code for PDF bookmark
}
% 4th Version
\section{%
    \texorpdfstring{$\mathsmaller{\mathtt{SQUARING}^{+}}$}% Code for text
                   {SQUARING+}% Code for PDF bookmark
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of adjusting the code that's used in the second argument of `\texofpdfstring`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! :)

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner **1.** I beg to disagree: `mathcal` is unbelievably ugly, regardless of size. Is there an alternative? **2.** I am writing for people absolutely convinced that mathematical writing is absolutely consistent. So, since I said I would use `mathcal`for proper names of functions, I have to, no matter where. **3.** They would immediately spot that the font in your section 2 above is different and wonder what it's supposed to indicate. So, I appreciate your help but can't use it. **4.** I have inserted the word Function in the section titles for it to look the way it does.

Comment: @schremmer I do not understand what you mean. The second \section in the provided answer does not use \mathcal.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuejner Sorry about that. I wanted to use some script font, say like Apple Chancery or Noteworthy, for proper names of functions because I want to support the impression that _functions_ are entities the way _numbers_ are entities. (My past in Category Theory showing up.) But donI have to use the same font _everywhere_, including section titles, for the reason I gave before.  I was hoping for exactly the first Squaring+ in your answer but in a section title.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuejner Sorry about that. I wanted to use some script font, say like Apple Chancery or Noteworthy, for proper names of functions to support the idea that _functions_ are entities the same way as _numbers_ are entities. (My past in Category Theory showing up?) But I didn’t know how to do that so I used `mathcal` for lack of anything better. But then I ran into the section problem. What I would like of course is exactly your first Squaring+ in a section title. In other words, the size of your section 2 but with mathcal for lack of anything better. (I couldn't remember how to delete.)

Comment: @schremmer I have added an edit (incl. `\mathtt` version). If that is what you want then it is very simple.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner  Of course, there is no changing the fact that `mathcal` is awful. But with section 3, you gave me what I think is the best I can hope for under the circumstances: at least, it is not overwhelming. As for mathtt, it’s nice but I think I need script to have something really “different”. So, thanks for all the work.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner [Squaring]{http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW/SmallMathCall.pdf}