# Warning when putting a math command in \section regarding "Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode)"

Tags: math-mode, sectioning, hyperref, amsmath, warnings

I am very new to LaTeX and I have been playing around with it by trying to transcribe my math notes into it. For some reasons when i wrote

```
\begin{math}\sqrt{2}\end{math}
```

after

```
 \section
```

Overleaf gave me a warning. Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

Here is the line of code

```
 \section{Proof of the Irrationality of\begin{math}\sqrt{2}\end{math}}
```

Here is the warning I was given:

> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `math shift' on input line 59.

I've already seen the [similar post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53513/hyperref-token-not-allowed) but I believe that using

```
 \section{Proof of the Irrationality of \texorpdfstring{\begin{math}\sqrt{2}\end{math}{}}
```

does not work because this shows up

> Your code has errors that need to be fixed before the auto-compile can run
> No PDF
> This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
> There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
> The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
> This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: What are you intending the arguments of `\texorpdfstring{\begin{math}\sqrt{2}\end{math}{}}` to be?  At the moment, the first argument is `\begin{math}\sqrt{2}\end{math}{}` and the second doesn't exist.  Move the `}` so this works, and the second argument can be `√2`.

Comment: Fixed it! Thank you. I also looked at another [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699195/how-to-use-texorpdfstring-correctly-and-properly) clarifying how \texorpdfstring works.